# Cannot convert from Expression< Func< Entity, bool> > to Func< Entity, bool>

Tags: c#, linq

I have this function in my code:

```
public virtual bool Exists<ENTITY>(Expression<Func<ENTITY, bool>> expr)
{
    return this._dbSet.Count(expr) > 0;
}
```

I get the error

> Cannot convert System.Linq.Expressions.Expression< System.Func< ENTITY, bool>> to 
>   System.Func< ENTITY, bool>

now if I change function to this:

```
public virtual bool Exists<ENTITY>(Expression<Func<ENTITY, bool>> expr)
{
    var tmp = expr.Compile();
    return this._dbSet.Count(tmp) > 0;
}
```

I get another error:

> Cannot convert System.Func< ENTITY, bool> to
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression< System.Func< ENTITY, bool> >

What am I doing wrong or is the compiler got crazy? Im using VS2017 C# 7.1

Comment: the two errors you mentioned are exactly the same

Comment: expression is method definition(like class), func is method reference (like instance), they are not the same.  you can call `expression.compile()` to get an instance func from expression.

Comment: You should never use `x.Count() > 0` as this may require your data source to fetch and count all your items just to check if there any, which is extremely inefficient. Use `x.Any()` as here only one item needs to be fetched to know if there are any items.

Comment: fixed the error message. no they are not same. it was the fruit of copy paste 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post your full code so I'm guessing here:

You *class* already *is* generic with a parameter `ENTITY`. So drop the `<ENTITY>` of `Exists<ENTITY>` because that means your method is generic *and different from your class*. But it must be the same generic parameter as the class and your `DbSet` so just use the class' generic parameter.

```
class Repository<ENTITY>
{
    public virtual bool Exists(Expression<Func<ENTITY, bool>> expr)
    {
        return this._dbSet.Count(expr) > 0;
    }
}
```

---

Sidenote: an EXISTS would probably be an `.Any()`, not `.Count() > 0`.

Comment: @nvoigt you were 100% correct. removing the <ENTITY> from exists fixed everything.

Answer (score 4):

**Assuming** that you want to count the entities in `_dbSet` that fulfill the predicate - **in order to check if there is any element at all**, after compiling the expression tree,

```
var tmp = expr.Compile();
```

you should add this: `return this._dbSet.Where(entity => tmp(entity).Count() > 0;`

**Update**

As already [nvoigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2060725/nvoigt) has pointed out in his answer, it would be more logical to use the `Any` method:

```
return this._dbSet.Any(entity => tmp(entity));
```

Comment: I changed that to Any(). thanks for nice piece of advice :)